# DB2 - coalesce - join

Tags: sql, db2

Given 3 tables. How can I choose the right join if two cases were possible.

Table1

| Article | CustomerID-extern | CustomerID-intern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table | A13590 |  |
| chair |  | B23877 |

Table2

| CustomerID-extern | CustomerID-intern |
| --- | --- |
| A13590 | BX13590 |

Table3

| CustomerID-intern | Customername | CustomerAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BX13590 | Microsoft | SiliconValley |
| B23877 | Amazon | New York |

In the result I need the CustomerID-intern with the assigned address of it.
In Table1 there can only be filled 1 field either CustomerID-extern or CustomerID-intern.

| Article | CustomerID-intern | Customername | CustomerAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table | BX13590 | Microsoft | SiliconValley |
| chair | B23877 | Amazon | New York |

Thank you.

Comment: Simply INNER JOIN the tables. (And I'd use OR for the extern/intern customer id.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two left outer joins to match rows in the third table accordind to the direct codes or the translation codes in the second table. For example:

```
select a.Article, c.*  
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.CustomerID_extern = b.CustomerID_extern
left join table2 c on c.CustomerID_intern = a.CustomerID_intern
                   or c.CustomerID_intern = b.CustomerID_intern
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.